# Django: separate shops

Tags: django

I would like to create a Django project which will do the following:

There is a platform example.com which already have a "shop" functionality (app). 
This platform should provide an ability to users to create their own store inside platform. 
Users can set up a a shop on and will receive a url like

```
user1.example.com 
user2.example.com
```

In this cases each url is a separate store.

The problem is: I don't know how to make each store to have its own shopping cart, order history, etc.
I just need an advice: what is best to use to solve this problem (maybe, sessions or some other Django features?)

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer a broad question like this but I'll try.

- I would start by designing the data models of your app. It's not related to Django. It just consists on finding what are the objects, and how they are related together. If you never did that before, take a look to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model)

It's in this model design that you will create most of the logic of your app. This is the "tool" you're looking for. For example, you will create your entities like `Shop`, `Customer`, `Owner`, and the relationships between them.

- Then, I would translate this at a Django level, using [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/)

After that, you should have the basis for your project. You will change some of your models over time, using Django migrations (because there is a new need or because you made a mistake in your initial model design)

Don't think of URLs now. URLs are just a way to reach a specific view on your app. You can deal with this later. Just ensure a proper model design first.